# Integrating Akamai with S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, akamai

I want to serve the contents stored in my S3 bucket with Akamai, not with Amazon CloudFront.

Is there any way to integrate Akamai with S3 bucket?

Answer (score 3):

Its quite huge sathya, but I suggest you to contact solution architect's. If you are configuring for the production systems. Its risks if you are doing it for the first time and things can go wrong. Any how I am writing the steps here, though it will not cover the all the steps.

GO to lunar control center and configure->tools->Edge hostnames-> Create edge hostname.

Make sure you have declared your s3 bucket as a static web site, it becomes easy to access. The name of the s3 bucket should be the name of the domain or sub-domain. Put the end-point of the bucket or your subdomain name and akamai will give you the end point. Copy the end point generated by akamai.

Go to configure->property->site
Choose the configuration name you want to add or create a new configuration from the exiting one, here you should be carefully. This were akamai people can help you to understand set the configurations.

Comment: Thank for your help Jeevan. I will try these steps.

Comment: Okay let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can integrate your S3 buckets with Akamai. Once you have access to the akamai's lunar control center you can do it. I have done it. Its better to contact Akamai customer support then posting here.

Comment: Can you list down the steps. We have access to Akamai and S3.